# How to get total count of field in reactive form along with valid and invalid fields?

Tags: angular

I have few fields on my form which are required and few fields which are not required.
I want to know the total fields and how many fields have been filled without violating any validation even if it's not required. So far tried this but I am not getting the expected result.

```
const controls = this.userForm.controls;
let totalControl = 0;
for (const name in controls) {
    totalControl++;
    if (controls[name].invalid) {
        invalid.push(name);
    }
}
const validControls = totalControl - invalid.length;
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-reactive-forms-yai41z?file=src/app/formreactive/formreactive.component.html

Here, I want count of total and invalid fields only when it's a required field.

Comment: Hello, please, update it if a stackblitz, so we can help better.

Comment: Please give more details: how is it not working? What do you expect? Also when is this code called..

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-reactive-forms-omrzk2?file=src/app/formreactive/formreactive.component.html
Here field "Last Name" is not required so total count of field, I should get is 3 and out of these 3 fields, I want to know which one are valid and which one are invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Form,

```
public form = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
    lastName: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
    firstName1: new FormControl(''),
    lastName1: new FormControl(''),
    firstName2: new FormControl(''),
    lastName2: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
    firstName3: new FormControl(''),
    lastName3: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
    firstName4: new FormControl(''),
    lastName4: new FormControl(''),
  });
```

And here is the function.

```
  check(){
    const controls = this.form.controls;
    const invalidArr = [];
    const validArr = [];
    for (const name in controls) {
      if (controls[name].status === 'INVALID') {
         invalidArr.push(name);
      }else{
        validArr.push(name);
      }
    }
    console.log(`valid count : ${validArr.length}`)
    console.log(`invalid count : ${invalidArr.length}`)
  }
```

Invalid will not work... :)

Comment: why not use `if (this.formGroup.get(name).invalid)`?